# How to recover Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu is my main OS and I have Windows as a VM. I made a mistake and rebooted while it was upgrading to 12.10 and now my machine cannot boot to OS.

How can I recover my files before I do a clean install?

Answer (score 1):

There are more options but I can list 3 from the top of my head

- Use a 'live cd' and boot from it, you can then mount discs and then can put your files to a backup using something like Brasero or command line.
- Enter grub rescue and use the command line to save your files to a backup.
- Re-install but do not format your discs and Ubuntu will leave your home intact. But this is risky ... if you make a mistake it will all be gone.